# Label or text box

Tags: nsis

So this is what I have for password set up. I would like to know how I make it so that the page has a lable or text box on it that Askes you to enter a password. As of rigth now it is blank. any ideas

```
!include "nsDialogs.nsh"
!include "winmessages.nsh"
!include "logiclib.nsh"

Page Custom pre leave



var dialog

var hwnd

Function leave

${NSD_GetText} $hwnd $0

${If} $0 != "Password"

    MessageBox MB_OK "Please enter a valid Security Code"

    Abort

${EndIf}

FunctionEnd

Function pre

 nsDialogs::Create 1018

  Pop $dialog



 ${NSD_CreatePassword} 0 0 50% 8% ""

     Pop $hwnd

 SendMessage $hwnd ${EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR} 149 0 # 149 = medium dot



nsDialogs::show

FunctionEnd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 2d 70d 16d "Password:"
Pop $0
${NSD_CreatePassword} 70d 0 50% 20d ""
Pop $hwnd
...
```